# Remove ranges that fall within other ranges

Tags: php

Here's an example of the expected result:

```
['name' => 'To Remove', 'start' => 1000, 'end' => 2000], # Nullified by 999 - 2001
['name' => 'To Keep 1', 'start' => 500, 'end' => 600],
['name' => 'To Keep 2', 'start' => 2001, 'end' => 2009],
['name' => 'To Keep 3', 'start' => 1513953789, 'end' => 1513953799],
['name' => 'To Remove', 'start' => 2001, 'end' => 2002], # Nullified by 2001 - 2009
['name' => 'To Remove', 'start' => 2005, 'end' => 2009], # Nullified by 2001 - 2009
['name' => 'To Keep 4', 'start' => 999, 'end' => 2001],
```

I tried this but it isn't working:

```
$x = array_filter($mys, function($current) use($mys) {
    foreach ($mys as $my):
        if ($current['start'] >= $my['start'] and $current['end'] <= $my['end'])
            return false;
    endforeach;

    return true;
});
```

Comment: you mean you want to unset ?

Comment: Question is unclear... Please describe clearly what you want....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there... But because you are using `>=` and `<=`, your forgot to prevent the `$current` item from comparing against itself...

I added `$my !== $current`

```
$x = array_filter($mys, function($current) use($mys) {
  foreach ($mys as $my):
    if ($my !== $current and $current['start'] >= $my['start'] and $current['end'] <= $my['end'])
      return false;
  endforeach;
  return true;
});
```

You may need to add an `array_unique()` if you have duplicate values, otherwise you can try using the key in the callback function...

```
  $x = array_filter( $mys, function( $current, $currentKey ) use( $mys ) {
  foreach ( $mys as $myKey => $my ):
if ( $currentKey != $myKey and $current['start'] >= $my['start'] and $current['end'] <= $my['end'] )
  return false;
  endforeach;
  return true;
 }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH );
```